# Better ways to transfer WebM DataURLS

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, byte

My problem is that Web-M Video Data-URLs which being pretty much are **video data as a link, are too hefty when transferring to a database like Firebase**. Firebase can only handle up-to 1,048,487 bytes and uni-code characters are 2 bytes so **Firebase can really only handle 524,243 characters** which is very little when it comes to Data-URL links. I'm using Data-URLs because I'm taking audio and camera stream blob data and converting it into a URL object because blob are only usable during that tab/session. Unless there is a better way to create data from navigator.MediaDevices' web-api, then I'm gonna need a new way to transfer the DataURL. Btw **I'm making this for a calendar/planner app so it's not just one video, it's many videos**. **But those are going to be in seperate fields so that's not too much to worry about**, just putting that in because **Firebase might have a size limit for how much data you can put in your entire database**.

**P.S, I already tried different encryption and encoders, like a ton of them**. All of them always increased the byte size by a couple of thousands or even double it which is the exact opposite of what I need. I even removed the boilerplate data at the start and just added that back when the video is being retrieved, "data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo". Even the encryption methods that work still result in videos that are around 150,000 bytes when the video is barely hitting two seconds in length which means that the max limit of the video's length is 13.84 seconds.

[image: Firebase byte overload size limit]

Comment: how big is the data url? by the way, the maximum string size in firebase is 10MB, not 1MB as you claim

Comment: @JaromandaX A simple 1.31 second video is 256,823 characters long

Comment: which is less than `524,243` so, not sure what the issue even is in that case

Comment: Well that was with videos that do work, the ones that don't are ones that are around 2,000,000 characters long / 4,00,000 bytes and only 10 seconds long.